# Compare two symbols that have almost 100% inverse correlation to identify the bars both tickers closed positive or negative

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to compare two symbols, that have almost 100% inverse correlation, to identify the days both tickers closed positive or negative (where they lose the inverse correlation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the close of both symbols and display bars wherever the close is in same direction. Example

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Indicator Merge By Rohit",overlay=true)
symbol1 = input.symbol("ZN1!","Symbol1")
symbol2 = input.symbol("ED1!","Symbol2")
close1=request.security(symbol1, timeframe.period, close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
close2=request.security(symbol2,timeframe.period, close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
bgcolor(((close1>close1[1] and close2>close2[1]) or (close1<close1[1] and close2<close2[1]))?color.new(color.red,70):na)
```

[image]